# DSpace 5.5 JSPUI Invert Item View

Tags: jsp, dspace

I want to invert the page of the display order of "item-view" in dspace.  I want to make the downloadable files shown above the table. Which parameters should I change? I believe I have to change something beyond display-item.jsp. Is it the item class file?  How do I do that? I am using DSpace 5.5 JSPUI.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The piece that puts the item metadata and files on the display-item.jsp page is the Item "tag".

This happens here:
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp/display-item.jsp#L191

To change the place where you are rendering the bitstreams, I think it's enough to move around the invocation of the "listBitstreams" method call in the ItemTag.java

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-jspui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/webui/jsptag/ItemTag.java#L629